# How do I access Find My Friends from iCloud.com?

Tags: icloud

I have been [reading](http://www.theverge.com/2015/10/22/9598800/find-my-friends-is-now-accessible-on-icloud-com) [that it is now possible](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/access-apples-find-my-friends-app-on-icloud-com/) to access Find My Friends [from iCloud.com](http://appleinsider.com/articles/15/10/21/find-my-friends-comes-to-the-web-via-apples-icloudcom),  and I have a friend who is able to do so from *their* iCloud.com account: It shows up in the iCloud menu under the URL "icloud.com/#fmf".  But when I log in this URL silently chops off the "fmf" part, the "Find My Friends" app doesn't show up from the menu, and when I try to use an invite from my friend, it tells me to install the app on my iPad.

I don't *have* an iPad. In fact I don't have *any* mobile devices which are made by Apple, which is the whole point of wanting to use iCloud.com.

How do I get Find My Friends to show up on my iCloud.com account?

Update: I found that I can enable iCloud on my *Mac* by going to `System Preferences -> iCloud` and signing into with Apple Id.  After I do this, `icloud.com/#fmf` works to the extent that it brings up a map, but I still can't see any friends.  Then, when I try to click on the link in the invitation from my friend, I get the following message:

```
Find my Friends

To view <friend's name> (<friend's e-mail>) location, open your
invitation in the Mail app on your iOS device and tap View Request. If the 
Find My Friends app is not installed on your device you can download it
free from the App Store.
```

Well.... once again I don't have an iOS device, and if I did I don't know how I would open the invitation in the Mail app, because my Apple Id is linked to a GMail account, not an iCloud account!

Answer (score 3):

You can't to my knowledge. [Find My Friends (sadly) requires an iOS or OS X device be configured for use with Find My Friends](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201493) at least once. If you have no Mac or iOS device, you can't. If that article wasn't clear enough (it's rather vague) [here's a more explicit one](http://help.apple.com/icloud/?lang=en-us#/mmee1c40b139).

> **Note:** If you don’t see Find My Friends on iCloud.com, your account just has access to iCloud web-only features. To gain access to other iCloud features, set up iCloud on your iOS device or Mac.

After you do that, *then* you can access it from the web.

Comment: Any possibility I could go into an Apple store, temporarily set up a device with my Apple Id, then after things are configured wipe my account from the device?

Comment: @Michael The Macs in an Apple Store prevent logging in to any services in System Preferences. You might have more luck with a Mac in a reseller store, but note there's a limit as to how many Apple IDs can be activated by one Mac.

Comment: I don't see that Note from the link, but I just noticed the quote you provided says "set up iCloud on your iOS device *or Mac*".  I'm accessing iCloud.com on my Mac already... but does this mean there is some way to set *it* up to allow Find My Friends to work?

Comment: Well, I actually got a bit further!  I found that if I go to System Preferences -> iCloud I can actually set up iCloud on my Mac, and then "Find My Friends" actually shows up in iCloud.com ... but I'm still not able to add a friend to the list.  I'll update my question to reflect the latest snag, as this is getting a bit lengthy for comments.